# Get a JSON tree of all comments of a post?

Tags: python, json, reddit

I'm looking to backup a subreddit to disk. So far, it doesn't seem to be easily possible with the way that the Reddit API works. My best bet at getting a single JSON tree with all comments (and nested comments) would seem to be storing them inside of a database and doing a pretty ridiculous recursive query to generate the JSON.

Is there a Reddit API method which will give me a tree containing *all* comments on a given post in the expected order?

Answer (score 0):

The number of comments you get from the API has a hard limit, for performance reasons; to ensure you're getting *all* comments, you have to parse through the child nodes and make additional calls as necessary.

Be aware that the subreddit listing will only include the latest 1000 posts, so if your target subreddit has more than that, you probably won't be able to obtain a full backup anyways.

Comment: Yes. I'm obviously going to keep iterating backwards, request by request, until I've reached the root. Comments are just hard. I want to store them in a way that respects their relationships/nestedness; the only way I've found of doing that is by storing them in a database. Storing them on the filesystem is too hard; I might receive a child comment before a parent.

Comment: Yes, and you can collect them into one big list and before storing them, sort said list in any way you want.